# Terminal doesn't see Windows filesystem until I open in Home Folder GUI

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, directory

I'm currently dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu.  When I try to access my Windows HD through the terminal I can't find it.  However, I used the Home Folder application to see where those drives/folders were.  And after I clicked into it in the Home Folder, I looked again at the same folder in the terminal and it appeared.  Is there a reason for this and how can I set it so I always can see those folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your windows drives are not mounted automatically during boot.When you click open the drive , Ubuntu mounts it for you automatically and hence you can see it through terminal.

If you want to open the drives in terminal then you will have to mount it manually using the `mount` command and then browse it through terminal.

Here's a tutorial that show you how http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/

To mount the partitions during boot then you should make the required entry to the `/etc/fstab` file There are also several tutorials available online that gives step by step instruction how to do that

Here's a detailed tutorial from Ubuntu which shows how to automatically mount partitions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I was thinking.. will have to try system-wide mounting now